# AWS API Gateway fails with "Unable to invoke" when query string contains key without value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

There is a resource `/{myvar}` defined in API Gateway, with `GET` method. Integration request points to Lambda function, with `Lambda Proxy integration` enabled.

When I invoke **test execution from API Resource Editor** of this resource and method, it works for queries like

```
/abc
/abc?def=ghi
```

but it fails to execute query like

```
/abc?def
```

with following response body visible in test console:

```
{
  "cause": "Unable to invoke. Please try again later.",
  "logref": "f6c905bd-cc71-11e8-a731-37e05a411010",
  "message": ""
}
```

and also Response Headers and Logs boxes below are empty.

<s>When I publish such resource to stage, accessing it through HTTPS in browser results with {"message": "Internal server error"}</s> See edit below

How to deal with that? How can I capture whole resource path with or without query, with no Gateway crash? It fails the same way also for greedy resource `/{myvar+}`.

---

**EDIT**

After redeployment problem no longer occurs on stage. It is still occurs within Method Execution window in API Gateway Resources Editor.

Answer (score 0):

you can capture the query string params through the "event" object sent to your Function Handler, it is called queryStringParameters. You can just log this and go through it on CloudWatch to see what exactly is failing.

P.S. Sorry for posting as an answer, don't have rep for comment ^^

Comment: It looks like in described case my function is not executed at all (Cloudwatch logs are empty)

Comment: What happens when you try to access the API GW endpoint from browser?